# C shell commands using process ID

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm not familiar with C, but can i create shell instance and execute commands in it?

As i understand, the C's `system` creates shell instance every call, can i reduce this some way? I want to make C calls interpreter of different languages: ruby, python, php. But creating shell instances via `system` every time is slow. Can i do smth like:

1. Start process (shell), write process id
2. Send commands to this process id like `python test.py`

Comment: And why don't you run the interpreter directly? Note: This can very easily become a security black hole.

Comment: You can do this by creating a program that listens for input through some [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) method, and then `fork` a new process to `exec` the command. Which is basically what a shell is doing. And yes, it's a really big security hole waiting to be uncovered.

Comment: PHP's `system` is slow because of "creating shell instance every call". I want to write C plugin, which allows to call another interpreters with no delay (now it's about 0.5-1 seconds for "Hello World")

Comment: You can just run other interpreters directly. No need to go through the shell.